# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for https://api.openweathermap.org API

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, weather-api, openweathermap

i try to get the weather information from https://api.openweathermap.org API but getting error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on browser console ..
below the my fiddle.....
https://jsfiddle.net/rahulchavan888/qvm7f8m4/

i use https but when i use http only for API the error:

`Mixed Content: The page at https://jsfiddle.net/rahulchavan888/qvm7f8m4/ was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=pune&APPID=eb46db75dae051cb28fe9ca0c1e8ec15". This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

please try to solve my problem ..thanks

Comment: You need to set the proxy to access this site.

Comment: how set the proxy to access??

Comment: but it need to work on any machine not only my..

Comment: is there any one help mi??